# Problem with knit (export to HTML or PDF)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I just tried to export my Rmd file to HTML in knit but I got error:
"object 'fmatrix' not found"
I already install and active R.matlab package and also include it in my code but it's not work!!
please help me what should I do!?
(Code run exactly but when I try to export to HTML I got this error)

I already install and active R.matlab package and also include it in my code but it's not work!!
please help me what should I do!?
(Code run exactly but when I try to export to HTML I got this error)

```
library(R.matlab)
```

```
graph_h <- graph.adjacency(fmatrix, mode = "directed", weighted = NULL)
```

(Code run exactly but when I try to export to HTML I got this error)

Comment: Do you see `fmatrix` in your Global.Env? If yes, you need `knitr` to be able to see this object by putting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)` into your Rmd file. If no, then simply you have the error because no such object exists in any environment.

Comment: @Marian Minar  Thank you - yes  dmatrix is in global.Env and I should only add knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE) to my code? I did it but still have problem :(  Is it possible that problem is fmatrix size? it is show as 1.8 G !!

Comment: No, the size should not give you that specific error. Is there any way you could make a reprex? (a small, reproducible example)

Comment: When you knit, R starts completely fresh and runs only those commands in your markdown file. So to check what's going on, restart R, and make sure it's not reading in any objects from a previous run, that is, your environment should be empty. Then start at the top of your markdown file and run all your chunks. You will at some point recreate the error, and then can figure out how to fix it. I suspect you read `fmatrix` into your R environment by either the menus or by a typing a command in the console, but didn't put the code in your markdown file.